# What information is available about a Domain Name

Tags: analytics, categories, ownership, country-codes

What information is available about a domain name (one that is registered) such as the owner. the company, industry, location, context it is used in, or other metadata about the domain name.

Comment: There are many possible sources of data about a domain.  Too many to list in an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The only publicly listed information is what you can see in a whois query.  But even then if the domain owner chooses to enable domain privacy (assuming it is available on that domain extension) you are unlikely to be able to see any info at all.

If your question is *really* about trying to get info about a domain where someone is squatting and they have nothing available publicly, then you won't find anything.